# Allow multiple selection when in edit mode of UITableView right on the beginning

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, edit, multiple-select

If a user presses a button in the toolbar the `UITableView` should show the round circles on the left of each row (like in the mail app if you click on *Edit*). With this the user can select multiple rows and performs some action like mark, delete, ...

As I found out you have to be in edit mode.

```
TableView.Editing = true;
```

Than you have to enable the multiple select with

```
TableView.AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
```

With this I should have the animation and the contents moves to the right a little bit. If I'm doing this the delete icons are first displayed (I don't want to delete). If I click on a table view cell as normal and I switch back to my tableview I get the checkmark behavior.

How do I get the multiple-select right on the beginning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be adding

> TableView.ReloadData();

The correct way would be to move

```
this.TableView.AllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true;
```

into `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, You want table view having cell with its contents and an "Edit" button which will bring the cell having a check mark to select the cell.

To achieve this you need to create Custom cell having check mark and the contents. Initially the the check mark will be hidden and the rest contents will start from the beginning(desired position). When the "Edit" is tapped the reload the table view and show the check mark & move the contents towards the right as you want.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it is too complicated for that what I want (which I think is a default behavior).